# Why is there no CalledFromWrongThreadException when a new thread operates UI immediately?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, exception

I was trying to dynamically add a view in to another view in MainActivity:

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.aronho.testfragment.MainActivity">
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/myView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

view_test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFF00">
<TextView
    android:text="testString"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I know this code will throw CalledFromWrongThreadException when I start the app:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View view=vi.inflate(R.layout.view_test,null);
        final FrameLayout parentView=(FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.myView);
        parentView.addView(view);

        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                }catch (Exception e){
                }
                parentView.removeView(view);
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

but when I remove the Thread.sleep(3000);,eg:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View view=vi.inflate(R.layout.view_test,null);
        final FrameLayout parentView=(FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.myView);
        parentView.addView(view);

        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                parentView.removeView(view);
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

the app doesn't throw CalledFromWrongThreadException despite I try to remove a view using a new thread. Why would that happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of the crash is the `ViewRootImpl.checkThread ()` method.

```
void checkThread() {

 if (mThread != Thread.currentThread()) {

  throw new CalledFromWrongThreadException( "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.");

}
```

However, the `invalidate ()` method is not called when the view is not measured , the `invalidate()` method will eventually execute to the `checkThread()`.

ok , see :

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.err.println("getMeasuredHeight:" + parentView.getMeasuredHeight());
            System.err.println("getMeasuredWidth:" + parentView.getMeasuredWidth());
            parentView.removeView(view);
        }
    }).start();
```

will get that:

```
W/System.err: getMeasuredWidth:0
W/System.err: getMeasuredHeight:0
```

can see, the measurement process has not been completed , so we can change the UI without triggering the `invalidate()` and not trigger exception.

then, keep it sleep 50 ms:

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.err.println("getMeasuredHeight:" + parentView.getMeasuredHeight());
            System.err.println("getMeasuredWidth:" + parentView.getMeasuredWidth());
            parentView.removeView(view);
        }
    }).start();
```

will get that:

```
W/System.err: getMeasuredHeight:360
W/System.err: getMeasuredWidth:1080
```

can see, the measurement process has been completed, then , when we change the UI the `invalidate` will be triggering,and then it call the `checkThread()`.

Answer (score 0):

In short, avoid manipulating Android UI elements off the UI Thread; you're going to run into unpredictable behaviour.

You can synchronize your update to the UI by using `Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable r)`, which should alleviate the problem. `i.e.`

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    // Synchronize on the UI Thread.
                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {  @Override public final void run() {
                        // Remove the View.
                        parentView.removeView(view); 
                    } });
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
```

However, there is a much better construct you should be using; you should never underestimate the computational burden of allocating and running a new `Thread`!

You can achieve the exact same functionality using:

```
(new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())).postDelayed(new Runnable() {  
     /* Update the UI. */ 
}, 3000));
```

This will achieve the same behaviour, without leaving you having to worry about managing synchronization along the UI Thread. Additionally, you won't be launching a whole new `Thread` whose only job is to sleep!

This should perform a  great deal better.

Comment: Also `parentView.post(() -> parentView.removeView(v));`  should work (as would `parentView#postDelayed` if a delay is required)

Answer (score 0):

No need to use a thread for a delay, instead :

```
 new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                }catch (Exception e){
                }
                parentView.removeView(view);
            }
        }).start();
```

Do :

```
  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    parentView.removeView(view);
                }
            }, 3000);
```