# Why onNext() is updating textview, though observeOn(Schedulars.io()) on a different thread?

Tags: android, rx-java2, rx-android

```
Observable.range(11,10).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new Observer<Integer>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(@NonNull Integer integer) {
                    textView.setText(String.valueOf(integer));
                    Log.d(TAG, "onNext: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            });
```

onNext() supposed to run on separate thread, but how is it updating textview, which is on main thread?

Comment: Please have a look at this description: http://tomstechnicalblog.blogspot.com/2016/02/rxjava-understanding-observeon-and.html?m=1

Comment: @HansWurst, can you explain why `onNext()` gets called on main thread, despite `observeOn(Schedulers.io())` ?

Comment: @Chandrim Gayen, this is interesting. Could you please print the log `Log.d(TAG, "onNext: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());` From my understanding, the Observer should be on IO Thread, but changing the UI should not be allowed. Which version of RxJava are you using?

Comment: Could it be that your are using Data Binding Library? If so, it seems that it is possible to [update UI off the main thread](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/generated-binding#background_thread).

Comment: @ChristianB, it can't be, except you used something like `RxJavaPlugins.setIoSchedulerHandler(scheduler -> Schedulers.trampoline());` to overwrite the `IO`-Scheduler. I tried your example and I get called on a IO-Worker-Thread. Could you please check, whether the IO-Scheduler is overwritten? You can do it with `RxJavaPlugins`.

Comment: @ChristianB, log is showing separate thread name, not UI thread. I am not using databinding.

Comment: @ChandrimGayen, could you please post minimal example project on github and post it here? I somehow think there is something more going on, which is impossible to guess.

Comment: @ChandrimGayen: Then it is a real puzzle. How do you inflate your view? Can you show how you get a reference of `textView`. Please put all usefull info into your post. Or as @HansWurst said, make a runnable example on GitHub, so we could try this out ourself.

Comment: @ChristianB, Simply Inflating by findviewbyid.

Comment: @ChandrimGayen: I see. Then I am out of ideas. For my understanding it should not work at all. If you can, please make a minimal example app on GitHub reproducing this issue. Then we can help more :)

Comment: @ChristianB, ok I will a create a git, but it will take time.

Comment: My guess is that the original code has a static operator call just before subscribe, rendering the range-subscribeOn-observeOn totally inert.

Comment: @ChristianB, [https://github.com/Chandrim/RxAndroidDemo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/rxandroiddemo/MainActivity.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that at the very beginning of the lifetime of a view, there is a very short timespan where you are able to change the view off the main thread.

As you started a thread off the main thread, directly in `onCreate()`, and this thread almost instantly returns a result (as there is no real work to do) you will not get a `CalledFromWrongThreadException` when you adjust the view.

If you put a short delay (maybe it is different on your machine) - for me, `50ms` was enough - before the work in the thread / Observable starts, you will see the expected `CalledFromWrongThreadException`.

```java
Observable.just("first")
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
  .delay(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
  .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
  .subscribe(item -> {
    textView.setText(item); // after the delay you will get a CalledFromWrongThreadException
  });
```

And this is not related to RxJava. Creating a Thread which updates the view immediately shows the same behavior:

```java
new Thread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    textView.setText("foo"); // no CalledFromWrongThreadException
  }
}).start();
```

Looks like this issue goes back to [ViewRootImpl](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/ViewRootImpl.java#8802) `checkThread()` which did not get called in this case. For further understanding follow the links below.

Despite, any change to a view should happen from the main thread. The scenario you have shown seems like a "lucky" side-effect.

**Documentation**

- [Android UI Not Crashing When Modifying View off UI Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51275964/14794380)
- [Why is there no CalledFromWrongThreadException when a new thread operates UI immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45504507/14794380)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Data Binding Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding), it allows to [update the UI off the main thread](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/generated-binding#background_thread).

> You can change your data model in a background thread as long as it isn't a collection. Data binding localizes each variable / field during evaluation to avoid any concurrency issues.

Answer (score 0):

observeOn is an async operation and after its processed , the result to pushed to onNext whixh is intended to run on the UI thread. They are changing the threading for us.Thats an advantage isnt? Its the feature of RxJava

Comment: This is not an answer. The question was: "how can the textview be updated off the main thread"!

Comment: Oh that cant be happening i guess.